# How can I stream the selection of colors from the native macOS color picker to Flutter using EventChannels?

Tags: flutter, cocoa, flutter-plugin, nscolorpanel, event-channel

I am attempting to add a feature to [macos_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/macos_ui) that allows the user to launch the native macOS color picker and stream back their color selections via `EventChannel`.

I am able to launch the picker (Cocoa's `NSColorPanel`), but the color selection does not get streamed back. When I run the example application via XCode, I can see that the color selections are registered, but they do not seem to be streamed back to Flutter through the `EventChannel`. What is the proper way to handle this? Is it even possible to stream these events back to Flutter, given that they take place in a native macOS view?

Here is the Swift code I have so far:

## MacosUIPlugin.swift

```swift
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

public class MacOSUiPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin, FlutterStreamHandler {
  private let colorPanelProvider: ColorPanelProvider
  private var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?

  init(colorPanelProvider: ColorPanelProvider) {
    self.colorPanelProvider = colorPanelProvider
    super.init()
  }
  
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
      name: "dev.groovinchip.macos_ui",
      binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger)

    let colorSelectionChannel = FlutterEventChannel(
      name: "dev.groovinchip.macos_ui/color_panel",
      binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger)
  
    let colorPanelProvider = ColorPanelProvider()
      
    let instance = MacOSUiPlugin(colorPanelProvider: colorPanelProvider)
    colorSelectionChannel.setStreamHandler(instance)
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "color_panel":
      colorPanelProvider.openPanel()
      result(true)
    default:
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }
  
  public func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
    print("listening to MacosUIPluginEvents")
    eventSink = events
    //colorPanelProvider.startStream()
    return nil
  }
  
  public func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
    eventSink = nil
    return nil
  }
}

extension NSColor {
  var hexString: String {
    let red = Int(round(self.redComponent * 0xFF))
    let green = Int(round(self.greenComponent * 0xFF))
    let blue = Int(round(self.blueComponent * 0xFF))
    let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
    return hexString as String
  }
}
```

## ColorPanelProvider.swift

```swift
import FlutterMacOS

class ColorPanelProvider: NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
  var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?
  let colorPanel = NSColorPanel.shared

  func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
    print("listening to ColorPanelProvider events")
    eventSink = events
    return nil
  }

  func openPanel() {
    colorPanel.setTarget(self)
    colorPanel.setAction(#selector(startStream))
    colorPanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    colorPanel.isContinuous = true
    startStream()
  }

  @objc private func currentColor() -> String {
    print("currentColor: \(colorPanel.color.asFlutterHexString)")
    return colorPanel.color.asFlutterHexString
  }

  @objc public func startStream() {
    print("starting ColorPanelProvider stream")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(currentColor),
      name: NSColorPanel.colorDidChangeNotification,
      object: colorPanel)
    
    eventSink?(currentColor())
  }

  func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
    eventSink = nil
    return nil
  }
}

extension NSColor {
  var asFlutterHexString: String {
    let red = Int(round(self.redComponent * 0xFF))
    let green = Int(round(self.greenComponent * 0xFF))
    let blue = Int(round(self.blueComponent * 0xFF))
    let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
    return hexString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "0xFF") as String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been on the right track, but there's a few things that require some fixing. There's three things:

1. In `MacosUIPlugin.swift` you need to listen to the `colorChannelProvider` instead of the `instance` in your `register` function. So you need to change the following line

```swift
colorSelectionChannel.setStreamHandler(instance)
```

to this:

```swift
colorSelectionChannel.setStreamHandler(colorChannelProvider)
```

2. In `ColorPanelProvider.swift` you listen to color changes in `startStream`. While that is the correct way to do it you have to hand in the `colorPanel` that sends these changes so that the function can access the color with `colorPanel.color`. The function signature should look like this:

```swift
@objc public func startStream(colorPanel: NSColorPanel)
```

3. When you register the `startStream` method as the target to receive updates from the `colorPanel` in `openPanel()` you need to set it up so that it will get called correctly. So change the second line of the method to look like this and everything works like a charm:

```swift
colorPanel.setAction(#selector(startStream(colorPanel:)))
```

Hopefully, this will fix everything. In case there's anymore problems, please let me know.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much!